# Remove a part of a JSON

Tags: javascript, json

When sending json data to client side, I get the data like this.

```
{"Data":{"rows":[{"id":1,"cell":["1","amila","amila","False"]},{"id":2,"cell":["2","rakhitha","rakhitha","False"]},{"id":3,"cell":["3","Chathura","Chathura","False"]},{"id":4,"cell":["4","Geethaga","Geethaga","False"]}]},"JsonRequestBehavior":0}
```

But I want to get the data without the "Data" attribute. Like this,

```
{"rows":[{"id":1,"cell":["1","amila","amila","False"]},{"id":2,"cell":["2","rakhitha","rakhitha","False"]},{"id":3,"cell":["3","Chathura","Chathura","False"]},{"id":4,"cell":["4","Geethaga","Geethaga","False"]}]}
```

How do I remove this "Data" part from the json object? Is it possible?

I access this data from this URL. 
api/matchingservicewebapi/GetUser

Comment: just use returnedJson.Data in your code... like mydatas = jsonreturn.Data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this :

```
var json = {"Data":{"rows":[{"id":1,"cell":["1","amila","amila","False"]},{"id":2,"cell":["2","rakhitha","rakhitha","False"]},{"id":3,"cell":["3","Chathura","Chathura","False"]},{"id":4,"cell":["4","Geethaga","Geethaga","False"]}]},"JsonRequestBehavior":0};

​json = json.Data;
```

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/vWPWt/)

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick respond. It is working perfectly and thanks a lot. But how do I do this in url? Can't I remove from the browser URL? Like this.. {api/matchingservicewebapi/GetUser/}.Data @manseUK

Answer (score 1):

use

```
<script >
var data = yourJson.data
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you manage the server (on url: api/matchingservicewebapi/GetUser) you need to change the output there.

Answer (score 1):

If you get the JSON results in a `results` variable, for example, you could do `results = results.Data`.